# JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS maximum length

Tags: java, jar

I have a simple jar with Hello.java:

```
class Hello {
   public static void main(String[] a) {
      System.out.println("Hello world!");
   }
}
```

I'd like to pass it some options via JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS. If value of $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS length is less or equal to 1024,  it is picked up:

```
$export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=$(for i in {1..43}; do echo -n "-Dmyapp.opt${i}="123456789" "; done)
$ echo $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS | wc -c
1023

java -jar hello.jar
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dmyapp.opt1=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt2=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt3=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt4=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt5=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt6=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt7=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt8=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt9=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt10=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt11=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt12=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt13=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt14=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt15=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt16=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt17=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt18=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt19=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt20=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt21=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt22=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt23=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt24=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt25=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt26=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt27=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt28=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt29=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt30=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt31=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt32=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt33=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt34=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt35=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt36=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt37=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt38=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt39=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt40=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt41=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt42=123456789 -Dmyapp.opt43=123456789
Hello world!
```

If value of $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS length is more than 1024, it's ignored:

```
$export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS+="$JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -Dmyapp.opt44=123456789"
$ echo $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS | wc -c
2070

$ java -jar hello.jar
Hello world!
```

Where from does JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS characters length limit comes from?
Is it possible to exceed 1024 char limit?

Comment: See my answer below about why it happens, technically. Why would you want to pass >1024 chars of JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS? Can't you pass the `-D` options to your `java` process directly?

Comment: @dnswlt I appreciate your help! Application starts in docker container via ENTRYPOINT script. The script (and Dockerfile) is provided with limited set of variables. I cannot modify it and pass the -D options directly. Provider recommends to use JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS. I'll probably request adding JAVA_OPT environment variable as JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS seems to have limits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's an interesting question! If you check the source code of the OpenJDK v7, in particular the [command line argument parser](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/9b0ca45cd756/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp), you'll see:

```
jint Arguments::parse_options_environment_variable(const char* name, SysClassPath* scp_p, bool* scp_assembly_required_p) {
  const int N_MAX_OPTIONS = 64;
  const int OPTION_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
  char buffer[OPTION_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

So the buffer size is limited to 1024, which exactly matches what your nice experiments confirmed :-)

However, I don't know of and did not find any official documentation as to why this limit exists.

Comment: Thank you for the research. I'm happy to award you a bounty.